# How to declare an array of values within an array of objects using JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array containing objects that have a key data which is an array of values. I am trying to push values into `data` but it's not working for me.

My expected result looks like this:

```
array = [
  { data:[3,2,5] },
  { data:[5,2,1] }
]
```

So I want to fill the data arrays. To do this, I have tried populating the arrays with a `for` loop:

```
var array = [];
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
  for(j=0;j<3;j++){
    array[i]["data"][j].push(2);
  }
}
```

But this is not working for me.

Comment: `push` is not a **value** method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these changes, which modify your existing code.  For an improved method, see the bottom

## Your Code

```js
var array = [];
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
  array.push({data:[]})        // create your object
  for(j=0;j<3;j++){
    array[i]["data"].push(2);  // you don't need '[j]' because the result of 'data' key is an array, so just push onto it
  }
}

console.log(array)
```

## Alternative Method

```js
let arr = [...new Array(2)].map(el=>({ data: new Array(3).fill(2) }));

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can't do this: `array[i]["data"][j].push(2)` without first initializing `array[i]`.</strike>

*In your case there's no need to initialize it with an empty array, instead you can simply assign the whole object to each* `[i]`

What you are trying to achieve is an array of objects where each object is of the form `{'data': []}`

So assume you have your input coming from an array:

```
const initialData = [[3, 2, 5], [5, 2, 1]];
```

To get that data in the form you want it, you would do:

```js
const initialData = [[3, 2, 5], [5, 2, 1]];
var array = [];
for(i=0;i < initialData.length; i++){
  array[i] = {'data':initialData[i]};   
}
    
console.log(array)
```

And here is a neater approach using some of [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/prototype)'s methods which I recommend checking out:

```js
const initialData = [[3, 2, 5], [5, 2, 1]];

const array = initialData.map(elem => {
  return {
    'data': elem
  };
})

console.log(array)
```

And if you want *neaterer* you can go with [mplungjan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60131172/how-to-declare-an-array-of-values-within-an-array-of-objects-using-js#comment106352197_60131209)

Comment: No need for the return as long as your wrap the object `const array = initialData.map(elem => ({ 'data': elem }));`

Comment: @mplungjan, true that, but since the OP seems not to have a good grasp on array methods just yet, I thought I'd keep it as readable as possible

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the array with: `const array = [...Array(2)].map(() => ({ data: [] }));`

Then you'll be able to access it with:

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++){
  for(j=0;j<3;j++){
    array[i].data[j] = 2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
let items = 2
let arr = Array.from({ length: items }, (item) => item = { data: [] })
for (let i = 0; i < items; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    let val = 2 // replace value here
    arr[i].data.push(val)
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```